# Don't know where the issue is?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having an issue with the output with this program. I'm getting an error message about converting from boolean to int, even though I don't see it. Is there a way I can use doubles in a switch statement or change over to if statements?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int hourlyWage = 0;
    int hour = 0;
    int grossPay = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the employee name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter an hourly wage:$ ");
    hourlyWage = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of hours worked: ");
    hour = input.nextInt();

    final double OVERTIME = 1.5;
    final double REG_HOUR = 40;

    switch(hourlyWage){
    case (hourlyWage >= 7.25):
        if(hour <= 40){
            grossPay = hour * hourlyWage;
        }
        else if(hour > 40){
            grossPay = (int) ((int) (hour * hourlyWage) + ((hour - REG_HOUR) * (hourlyWage * OVERTIME)));
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("The wage entered is too low. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1);
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("ABC Manufacturing Company");
    System.out.println("Name  Hours  Pay");
    System.out.printf("%s  %.2f  $%.2f", name, hour, grossPay);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Also it is probably a good idea to use the title of the question wisely to point out the problem you are facing

Comment: Converting boolean to an int but I don't have a boolean present.

Comment: `case (hourlyWage >= 7.25)` is wrong here. Please look up how `switch` statements work and what allowed values for `case` are.

Comment: Care to share the error stacktrace?

Comment: *"but I don't have a boolean present"* What do you think is the result of `hourlyWage >= 7.25`? Maybe a boolean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line

```
case (hourlyWage >= 7.25):
```

hourlyWage >= 7.25 is an expression that evaluate to true, or false (boolean).

I really don't see why you need a switch here, you could do :

```
if(hourlyWage >= 7.25){
    if(hour <= 40){
        grossPay = hour * hourlyWage;
    }
    else {
        grossPay = (int) ((int) (hour * hourlyWage) + ((hour - REG_HOUR) * (hourlyWage * OVERTIME)));
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("The wage entered is too low. Please try again.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```